# For loop isnot working as expected in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, for

For loop is not executing properly for article Length 1  & 2.

If Article Length 3 its failing.

```
 var article = response.getReturnValue();
            alert('article lenght:'+article.length+'article'+JSON.stringify(article));
            for(var i=0;i<article.length;i++){
            alert(i); //In case of 3 its 0,1,2
                if(article[i].Product__r.Name!='' && article[i].Product__r.Name!=null && typeof article[i].Product__r.Name!='undefined'){
                  if( /\d/.test(article[i].Product__r.Name.split(','))){
                     prodVersions.push(article[i].Product__r.Name.split(','));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     allProducts.push(article[i].Product__r.Name.split(','));                            
                  }
                }                    
            }  //for loop
```

If its 3

I need to make

```
   for(var i=1;i<article.length;i++)
   {
   }
```

Then it will work.

How to make for loop properly for all 1,2,&3

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong, but is that supposed to be `article.length - 1` ? Since we are dealing with indexes which starts with 0. And your loop starts with 0 also. Try changing it to `article.length - 1` and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: i dont think so.if article length is 2 above code was working & in case of more than 3 its breaking!!

Comment: how many records are inside your `article` ?

Comment: Updated the questn

Comment: you should also change `'undefined'` to `undefined` without quotations.

Comment: Have you tried the `article.length - 1` yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the for loop itself, but the if-else statement is suspect. Here, you're basically removing all the commas and testing on what's left. Presumably, you're trying to check each individual element of `Product__r.Name.split(",")`, so your code should look more like this:

```
var articles = articles.getReturnValue();
articles.forEach(article => {
    // non-empty value
    if (article.Product__r.Name) { 
        let names = article.Product__r.Name.split(",");
        // all indexes with a digit are added to prodVersions
        prodVersions = prodVersions.concat(names.filter(value => /\d/.test(value)));
        // all indexes without are added to allProducts
        allProducts = allProducts.concat(names.filter(value => !(/\d/.test(value))));
    }
});
```